# Deprecated: mysql_connect()

Tags: localhost

I have a project to upgrade Wordpress from 3.6.1 to 4.3.1.

I've installed WAMPserver 2.5, and deployed the Wordpress site locally, but when I load the local website, I receive:

> ( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated
>   and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\wamp\www\site\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1142

`\wp-includes\wp-db.php` contains the following @ line 1141:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
            $this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
        } else {
            $this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
        }
```

Advice on where to go from here appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your WAMP settings and enable php_mysqli extension. You can do that within the toolbar menu on the right. Just right click on the WAMP icon and go to PHP extensions menu.

PHP 5.5 will warn about the deprecated mysql driver functions. Turn off warnings by setting Debug to false in the `wp-config.php`, or use a database layer such as this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mysqli/).

Comment: `php_mysqli` extension is already enabled.

Comment: Then restart all, if that does not work then check your apache log for errors. It's possible mysqli is not loading for some reason. Plus, make sure there is a check mark next to the extension!

Comment: But Wordpress 3.6.1 does not use `mysqli`.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the debug setting

Comment: Thanks. I already tried the plugin, and I think that is the answer. Just correcting my site files atm.